# How can I generate an elasticsearch query from a boolean expression, using Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'd like to "translate" a string like:

```
A AND (C OR B) AND NOT D
```

into an Elasticsearch query like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "text": "A"
        }
      },
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "text": "D"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "text": "B"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "text": "C"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

does exists some library which I can use ?
any help appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `A AND (C OR B) AND NOT D` is a valid query (Lucene expression syntax) when used inside a `query_string` query and is translated internally by ES to the second query you showed.

Comment: You mean this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html ? thanks! Going to read it

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: works fine, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad that was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

ok according to:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

I can do query like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "default_field" : "text",
            "query" : (this AND (submitted OR flowers) AND NOT blight"
        }
    }
}
```

which works great.